# Log4j2 throws NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I upgraded from log4j2 `2.0-beta9` to `2.0`, both `log4j-core` and `log4j-api`.

My application used to run fine before, now I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/Level;Lorg/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:336)
    at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:423)
    at com.mchange.v2.log.log4j.Log4jMLog$Log4jMLogger.log(Log4jMLog.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.log.log4j.Log4jMLog$Log4jMLogger.log(Log4jMLog.java:183)
    at com.mchange.v2.cfg.MConfig.dumpToLogger(MConfig.java:101)
    at com.mchange.v2.cfg.MConfig.dumpToLogger(MConfig.java:98)
    at com.mchange.v2.cfg.MConfig$CSManager.recreateFromKey(MConfig.java:154)
    at com.mchange.v1.cachedstore.NoCleanupCachedStore.find(NoCleanupCachedStore.java:63)
```

What might be wrong here? Why is log4j failing?

Maybe I have to redirect the logging from c3p0? How would the following statement have to be written in log4j2?

```
com.mchange.v2.log.MLog=com.mchange.v2.log.log4j.Log4jMLog
```

I discovered that the following statement will prevent c3p0 logging and thus is my current workaround:

```
System.setProperty("com.mchange.v2.log.MLog", "com.mchange.v2.log.FallbackMLog");
```

But I'd like to have the logging redirected to log4j2, so still looking for a solution.

Comment: were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Update: at the time of this writing the latest version is Log4j 2.6.2. Which is garbage-free, so please upgrade if you're still on an older version.

About the error: did you remember to also upgrade the adapter module (log4j-1.2-api-2.0-beta9.jar) from beta9 to 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the beta version has this problem. Upgrade it to 2.X